# help i've overwritten my /home/user directory

Tags: mount, data-recovery

I have stupidly mounted /dev/loop0 in two places - 
it is mounted on / and on /home/user

is it possible to unmount this and restore the folders in my /home/user folder ?
i can't even access the internet since the pathnames are no longer the same so I am on a different computer i.e. icons in the unity dock can't be accessed so I cant run any programs. Have I destroyed my files?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't think that your files would be destroyed. I would umount /dev/loop0 from /home/user and you should be fine.